# How to integrate this one $\int _{0}^{\infty} A(x)\ln(A(x))dx$ Definition of A are below.

Tags: calculus, integration

I do a project about quantum mechanics at school and found this one. I can't integrate this one. Please, help me.

$$\int _{0}^{\infty} A(x)\ln(A(x))dx, \text{ when } A=\dfrac{1}{k}\dfrac{\frac{5}{4}x^2-\frac{93}{32}x+\frac{95}{24}}{1+e^{\beta(x-a)}}$$

with the condition $k>0, \beta>0, a>0$.

Comment: Using u-v rule for integration, taking $u=ln(A(x))$ and $v=A(x)$ you can get rid of $ln$.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I also can't do this integral even don't have $ln$. @gemspark

Comment: Can this integral do by Wolfram Mathematica when all constant subtituted? I don't have Mathematica at my PC, but it's in my school's computer. Please, anybody check it forme.

Comment: If you just take $\int A(x)$, taking numerator as $u$ and denominator as $v$, you will be able to eliminate all powers of x and will only have an exponential expression to integrate at the end, which is straightforward.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has to be evaluated numerically. ([Here's how in Python](https://repl.it/repls/CreepyNavajowhiteEyestrain).) @gemspark's description of integration by parts contains an error, as we'd need $dv/dx=A$.

Comment: @J.G. Can you provide some proof/reasoning as to why you think this expression is not manually integrable?